# Why is blender doing this?

Tags: modeling

If you look at the spot, shape is taken side by side, but strangely, that red dot is sticking out. What's the problem? It wasn't edge crease problem.[image]

Comment: Hello :). Don't you have double vertices there?

Comment: no double vertex. The dots should be off the surface, but they stick together. I don't even know why this problem happened.

Comment: It's as if that subdivision isn't applied to that

Comment: I'm not good at guessing, could you [share the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? :)

Comment: I soluted this problem. it's normal problem.  thank you for your attention